# Emma does not display uncovered packages in the report

Tags: java, maven, emma

I am using maven with emma to generate coverage report on linux red hat. After I run command `mvn emma:emma`, packages which are not covered by JUnit tests are not displayed in the report.

I am using following configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>    
</plugin>
```

Any idea what is going on?
Or any way to make sure all packages including uncovered are part of report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**note** this was supposed to be a comment, and It doesn't answer not answer the question directly. It questions the usefulness of the question.

Quit using emma and start using [jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/). AFAIK, emma has been dormant since around 2007. The latest version of the emma plugin on maven central is from 2010.

As of today (fist quarter 2013). There is a [version on maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jacoco%7Cjacoco%7C0.6.2.201302030002%7Cpom) from feb-2013.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.2.201302030002</version>
</dependency>
```

And it is synchronized with the maven plugin. Here is an example of a configuration of mine

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
           <exclude>**/entities/*</exclude>
           </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <goals>
                 <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
           <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The reports from jacoco also look nicer than the ones in emma.

Compare:
[image: A screenshot of a sample report from the emma website]

with
[image: A screenshot of a sample report from the jacoco website]

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, it served the purpose.